# Is there a way to disable focussing of elements when a key is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have implemented a first page of an Angular app. This page displays a sidebar-menu, the menu-items of which are a-tags, as well as a table and an image. When hovering above the image and pressing the right-arrow key, the image is replaced with another component.

The issue that I have is: When clicking on a table row and afterwards hovering above the image and pressing the right-arrow key, the table row is focussed. Similarly, when clicking on a menu-item and then switching back to the original menu-item, this a-tag will be focussed when pressing the right-arrow key.

Obviously, I don't want any elements to be focussed when pressing the right-arrow key. The app behaves in the expected way if I click somewhere on the page before hovering above the image. So I am wondering: Is it possible to focus the entire page, maybe, before listening to a key-down event? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Disabled the key event on your table by capturing the event on a function and stop propagation